# Can't change the color of SpecialKey

Tags: vim

[image]

I have:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:\$\ 
hi SpecialKey ctermfg=161 guifg=161
```

But that's all I see. I did `161` for the color too so it'd be obvious if it were colored correctly (161 is like a pink/purple).

I'm using iTerm2 and `xterm-256color` is enabled. I'm using vim 7.3 on OS X Lion. Also, what's more strange, is this worked fine until I changed computers. I copied my `.vim` and `.vimrc` and everything works except the coloring of listchars... I changed from a non-retina MBP to a retina one, but otherwise everything else is the same.

Comment: Have you tried calling `:hi SpecialKey ctermfg=161` in vim while it's running? It could be the sequence you're calling it at.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you change font?

Comment: @Conner No, I quit vim and restart after I save the vimrc file each time, but yes, doing that in vim makes it work. WAT?! I didn't change the ordering when I copied it from my old machine. I'll move that line around tho to figure out the sweet spot.

Comment: @Peter yes. Different font, same colors :(

Comment: Found the right ordering. If you post your answer as an actual answer i'll mark it as right :)

Comment: Hah, mine stays the same even when I call it directly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the ordering. I'm not sure where exactly the conflict was, but I moved it up towards the top and it started working again. Not sure why this would have changed between computers, but this solved the issue.